# ¿Cómo comprobar en vivo dos campos con Ajax?

Tags: java, html, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de hacer una comprobacion del campo usuario y cedula en vivo , el realiza la consulta pero cuando ingreso la cedula realiza la busqueda y me muestra el error de que falta el index de usuario

Aqui dejo el codigo, Este es el archivo ajax.php

```
<?php
sleep(1);
$con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '' );
mysql_select_db('sisteman');
if($_REQUEST) {
 $cedula = $_REQUEST['cedula'];
 $query = "select cedula from users where cedula = '".strtolower($cedula)."'";
 $results = mysql_query( $query) or die(mysql_error());
 if(mysql_num_rows(@$results) > 0)
    echo '<div id="Error">Cedula ya existente</div>';
 else
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("ad").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("full-name").disabled =false;
        document.getElementById("username").disabled =false
        document.getElementById("password").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("status").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("level").disabled = false;
        </script>';
 }
?>

<?php
sleep(1);
$con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '' );
mysql_select_db('sisteman');
if($_REQUEST) {
 $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
 $query = "select username from users where username= '".strtolower($cedula)."'";
 $results = mysql_query( $query) or die(mysql_error());
 if(mysql_num_rows(@$results) > 0)
    echo '<div id="Error">Cedula ya existente</div>';
 else
    echo '    <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("ad").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("full-name").disabled =false;
  document.getElementById("username").disabled =false
  document.getElementById("password").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("status").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("level").disabled = false;
</script>';
 }
 ?>
```

y la funcion js es

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {    
$('#cedula').blur(function(){

    $('#Info').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" />').fadeOut(1000);

    var cedula = $(this).val();        
    var dataString = 'cedula='+cedula;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#Info').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
        }
    });
});             

 $('#username').blur(function(){

    $('#nfo').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" />').fadeOut(1000);

    var username = $(this).val();        
    var dataString = 'username='+username;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#nfo').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
        }
    });
});             
});    
</script>
```

Cada input tiene su id establecido y el error que sale es Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\sadm\ajax.php on line 95

Comment: Si enseñas el código, por lo pronto, quedará bastante más claro que es lo que está ocurriendo. En todo caso, me suena a que no has puesto el ID que toca en el campo usuario y jQuery es incapaz de detectarlo. Enséñanos el código por si es otra cosa.

Comment: Ya le agregue las lineas de codigo

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 95? ¿Segura que el request tiene un campo llamado "username"?

Comment: La linea 95 es $username = $_REQUEST['username']; y si es un input que tiene ese id, lo raro es que ese error me sale cuando estoy ingresando la algo en el campo de cedula y si ingreso algo en el campo de usuario lanza el mismo error pero dice que el index que no esta definido es el de cedula

Comment: el error dice que no tienes un index llamado username en $_REQUEST, si haces un var_dump($_REQUEST); que te muestra?

Comment: array(1) { ["cedula"]=> string(2) "32" }  es decir solo me esta tomando el primer request, los dos campos no los lleno al mismo tiempo, es decir primero ingreso el de cedula y luego de usuario, sera por eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

Como a este archivo llegas a veces con un Request con el index cedula y otra veces con un index username debes preguntar si existe ese index particular con la funcion [isset()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

```
<?php
sleep(1);
$con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '' );
mysql_select_db('sisteman');

if(isset($_REQUEST["cedula"]) { //<-- Verificas que exista el index "cedula"

    $cedula = $_REQUEST['cedula'];
    $query = "select cedula from users where cedula = '".strtolower($cedula)."'";
    $results = mysql_query( $query) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows(@$results) > 0)
        echo '<div id="Error">Cedula ya existente</div>';
    else
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("ad").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("full-name").disabled =false;
            document.getElementById("username").disabled =false
            document.getElementById("password").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("status").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("level").disabled = false;
            </script>';
}

if(isset($_REQUEST["username"]) { //<-- Verificas que exista el index "username"

    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $query = "select username from users where username= '".strtolower($cedula)."'";
    $results = mysql_query( $query) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows(@$results) > 0)
        echo '<div id="Error">Cedula ya existente</div>';
    else
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("ad").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("full-name").disabled =false;
            document.getElementById("username").disabled =false
            document.getElementById("password").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("status").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("level").disabled = false;
            </script>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Asi sirvio, muchisimas gracias!